# Mystery about my Mini-C parsing with Flex/Bison

Tags: parsing, yacc, flex-lexer

I'm trying scanning and parsing the mini-C code with lex and yacc, and I got some troubles.

I set tokens in `scanner.l` File like below,

```
...
"const"                return tconst
"int"                  return tint
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*   return tident
...
```

and I declare production rule in `parser.y` File

```
...
dcl_specification        : dcl_specifiers                { semantic(8); };
dcl_specifiers           : dcl_specifier                 { semantic(9); }
                         | dcl_specifiers dcl_specifier  { semantic(10); };
dcl_specifier            : type_qualifier                { semantic(11); }
                         | type_specifier                { semantic(12); };
type_qualifier           : tconst                        { semantic(13); };
type_specifier           : tint                          { semantic(14); };
...
%%
...
void semantic(int n) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
...
```

then, I want to parse the text `const int max=100`,
result is

```
13
11
9
8
syntax error
```

I expect `10` shows up because `const int` might be reduced by rule 10,
but I'm wrong.

why this happens and what should I do?

please let me know

Comment: You cannot `return` from a bison semantic action. Is that really an excerpt from your code?

Comment: @rici you're right. I just edited question with my real code. sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Does bison warn you about shift/reduce conflicts?

Comment: It did, but I fixed it

Comment: It's not possible to say why `dcl_specification` is being reduced early without seeing the entire context in which `dcl_specification` is used, but I can't help but think it has something to do with an S/R conflict. Perhaps you resolved the conflict in the incorrect direction.

Comment: okay.. may be I should ponder this problem carefully or ask professor for advice. anyway, thanks for your kind concern rici!

Comment: place an %error-verbose in your yacc declaration section, and you will have a much more comprehensive error message. By the way you should post the whole grammar, and another point is that yacc/bison will prompt you any S/R R/R conflict while compiling.. check for it and let us know..